# My JFrame Background won't change

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to Java and I have been given advice to learn java through small games. So I am trying to make a small Pong game and I have done a player that moves just as I wanted but the color background that I had before its not showing anymore. I try many methods but I truly don't know the error here. Here is my code:

Window Class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window{
  public Window(){
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    Player player = new Player();
    window.setSize(720, 480);
    window.setResizable(true);
    window.setTitle("2DGame");
    window.setUndecorated(false);
    window.setBackground(new Color(16,16,16));
    window.getContentPane().add(player);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(720, 480));
  }
}
```

Player Class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Player extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
  Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
  private int speed = 2;
  private int ydirection = 0;
  private int x = 28;
  private int y = 190;
  private boolean key1 = false;
  private boolean key2 = false;
  public Player(){
    t.start();
    addKeyListener(this);
    this.setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
  }
  public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(new Color(50, 50, 50));
    g.fillRect(x, y, 20, 100);
  }
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    repaint();
    y += ydirection;
  }
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    int KeyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W){
      ydirection = -speed;
      key1 = true;
    }
    if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S){
      ydirection = speed;
      key2 = true;
    }
    if(key1 == true && key2 == true){
      ydirection = 0;
    }
  }
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    int KeyCode = e.getKeyCode();
    if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W){
      ydirection = 0;
      key1 = false;
    }
    if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S){
      ydirection = 0;
      key2 = false;
    }
    if(KeyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE){
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}
}
```

Your answers would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Top Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html). It shows the hierarchy of a frame which consists of the frame, the content pane and components you add to the content pane.

> But my custom color in the window class is not showing up and instead, the background shows black

Again, the content pane covers the frame so you see the black. You should just be setting your custom color to the content pane, not the frame itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your problems include: you're setting the color of the contentPane but are covering it over by adding an opaque component (the JLabel) to the contentPane's `BorderLayout.CENTER` position. Again, this completely covers the contentPane.

Suggestions to help solve your problem and other unrelated suggestions:

- Make the Player JPanel non-opaque by calling `setOpaque(false)` on it. This way any background color on the container that holds it will show through.
- Or simply set the background color of the Player JPanel since it is now acting as contentPane, since it covers the center portion of the actual contentPane.
- Side recommendation 1: don't override the JPanel's paint method but rather its paintComponent method since paint is involved with painting child components and borders, something you don't want to cause side effects with, and because paint does not utilize the JPanel's double buffering, so your animation will be smoother if you override paintComponent.
- Use Key Bindings not a KeyListener for less hassle over GUI focus kludges.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I added setOpaque(false) and changed the paint method to paintComponent. But my custom color in the window class is not showing up and instead, the background shows black. Could you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
JFrame window = new JFrame();
window.getContentPane.setBackground(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JFrame window = new JFrame();
getContentPane().setBackground(Color.YELLOW); // ANY COLOR YOU WANT.
```

But if you want to put Image in your background. Try this.

```
setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C:\\Downloads\\file Sample.png")));
```